# Laravel Unit Testing AuthController

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, authentication, phpunit

I'm really new to unit testing and I want to try it with Laravel 5.0.

I just created a AuthTest and implemented a method for checking if a user is known (stored in database) and the credentials are correct.

I don't know really how to test it in a best practice way. Here is what I've done so far:

```
public function testIfCorrectCredentialsAreAccepted()
{
    $credentials = [ '_token' => csrf_token(), 'username' => 'test', 'password' => 'test' ];

    $user = User::create([ 'username' => $credentials['username'], 'firstname' => 'Test', 'surname' => 'Test' ]);

    $this->call('POST', '/auth/login', $credentials);
    $this->assertTrue(\Auth::check());

    DB::table('users')->where('username', $user->username)->delete();
}
```

The known users are stored inside the database, but the credential Validation is done over adLDAP with ldap-connector (Laravel Service Provider for extending Laravel Auth).

Am I going the right way, or am I failing just at the beginning?

Thank you!

Comment: You should add a test with wrong credentials. Also, you should delegate the creation/deletion of users to setup/teardown methods.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini But how do I know that my login is working, when the test with wrong credentials always works, because im asking for assertFalse(\Auth::check());? Sorry, but I'm really a newbie to unit testing.